# VeeValidate with Yup: input type="number" value is converted to string on submit

Tags: vue.js, yup, vee-validate

I use VeeValidate and Yup for form validation and don't know why my input field with type="number" is converted to string on submit.

When I input 78 and submit the form the output of the console.log in the onSubmit(values) function is the following:

```
values: {
   prioritaet: "78"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is this the normal behavior of VeeValidate and Yup? I would like to have a number instead of a string after submit.

My code looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="container m-3">
    <div class="row bg-primary align-items-center py-2">
      <div class="col">
        <h3 class="text-light mb-0">Format {{ this.action }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <h5 class="text-light mb-0">{{ this.formatTitle }}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>

    <Form @submit="onSubmit" :validation-schema="formatSchema" v-slot="{ errors }" ref="formatForm">
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col">
          <h5>Formatdaten</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-4">
          <label for="prioritaet-input">Priorität: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <Field type="number" name="prioritaet" id="prioritaet-input" class="w-100" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-auto me-auto">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Änderungen übernehmen</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Abbrechen</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button type="sumbit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Speichern</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row mt-4">
        <template v-if="Object.keys(errors).length">
          <span class="text-danger" v-for="(message, field) in errors" :key="field">{{ message }}</span>
        </template> 
      </div>
    </Form>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { Form, Field } from "vee-validate";
import deLocale from "../assets/yup-localization.js";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { markRaw } from "vue";

import { mapActions, mapState } from "vuex";

Yup.setLocale(deLocale);

export default {
  name: "FormatBearbeitungsSchirm",
  props: ["material_id"],
  data() {
    let action = "neu";
    let formatTitle = "Format neu";

    let formatSchema = markRaw(Yup.object().shape({
      prioritaet: Yup.number().min(1).max(100).integer().label("Priorität"),
    }));

    return { formatSchema, action, formatTitle };
  },
  created() {

  },
  components: {
    Form,
    Field,
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit(values) {
      console.log("values", values);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You must use the `number` modifier to tell Vue it is in-fact a number. `<input type="number" v-model.number="mynumber" />`

Comment: I already tried but it still remains a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is currently no support for specifying the `.number` modifier on the internal field model value of `<Field>`, so the emitted form `values` would always contain a string for `number`-type fields.

One workaround is to convert the value in the template, updating [`<Form>`'s `values` slot prop](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/components/handling-forms#form-values) in [`<Field>`'s `update:modelValue` event](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field):

```html
<Form @submit="onSubmit" v-slot="{ values }">
  <Field                             
    type="number"
    name="prioritaet"      
    @update:modelValue="values.prioritaet = Number(values.prioritaet)"
  />

  <button>Submit</button>
</Form>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-convert-number-field-value-6vx82?file=/src/components/MyForm.vue:142-215)

Another simple workaround is to convert the property inside `onSubmit` before using it:

```js
export default {
  onSubmit(values) {
    values.prioritaet = Number(values.prioritaet)

    // use values here...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `.number` modifier.

You can read about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number)

> If you want user input to be automatically typecast as a Number, you can add the number modifier to your v-model managed inputs:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
      mynumber1: undefined,
      mynumber2: undefined
  }),
  methods: {
    submit() {
      console.log(typeof this.mynumber1, this.mynumber1)
      console.log(typeof this.mynumber2, this.mynumber2)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
  <!-- number modifier -->
 <input type="number" v-model.number="mynumber1" placeholder="Type here" />
  <!-- no modifier -->
 <input type="number" v-model="mynumber2" placeholder="Type here" />
 <input type="button" @click="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
</div>
```